# What are the performance differences in using a service to share data between angularjs controllers vs $emit / $broadcast vs nested views?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-controller

I know from experience that internal communication between controllers should--when at all possible--not be implemented using `$emit` and `$broadcast` with `$watch`--this introduces perhaps unnecessary dependencies and is difficult to map, both mentally and physically--looking around for `$emits` is no way to track `$scope` changes.

Many advocate sharing data with services which also includes introducing `$watch`[ers] into controllers. Nesting views and sharing $scope is another option though it may not always be possible.

Does anyone have any readily available info on how these different techniques affect performance in a general manner?

I understand that the subtleties and nuances of angular app performance are difficult to pinpoint when complex app are implemented and dependencies start stacking up, but it would be very informative to the angularjs community (and myself of course), if one could discuss the performance differences between `$scope` sharing techniques among controllers.

The correct answer will detail the three techniques stated above and discuss their virtues and pitfalls as they relate to angularjs app performance. Thank you.

Comment: I fail to see why using events or using a service would imply using $watch. How about telling us what you want to do, and come up with some code you tried?

Comment: one use of $watch is to detect $scope changes and keep controllers in sync--the question is about the techniques of sharing data and their respective performance not a specific piece of code. There is a lot of material out there detailing the different ways of sharing data between controllers. This question is not about how to do it, but the consequences of doing it specific ways. It requires a broad understanding of angular controllers and $scope, broader and deeper than I have. I'm sure many would benefit from such an explanation.